# ¿Por qué window.window = window?

Tags: javascript, web, dom

```js
console.log(window.window.window.window.window);
```

¿Por qué `window.window = window`? ¿Para qué sirve? ¿Es un error de diseño?

Comment: Simplemente el objeto window tiene una propiedad window que almacena la referencia del el mismo como por ejemplo function Hola(){ 
  this.Hola = function(){
    console.log("ejecutando hola()")
    return this; 
  }; 
}

new Hola().Hola().Hola().Hola();

Comment: @Einer Entiendo que eso lo sabe, pero no entiende la utilidad de tener ese atributo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es un error de diseño, es más bien una limitación del intérprete: es la única forma de acceder al objeto global que es una instancia de la clase `Window`. Por ejemplo, cuando haces uso de algo tan cotidiano como `document.getElementById(...)`, en realidad no hay una variable `document`, es un atributo del objeto global. Es decir, en realidad estás llamando a

`<objetoGlobal>['document'].getElementById`

¿Pero qué pasa cuando quieres acceder precisamente a ese objeto global? Pues que no tiene un nombre conocido. Entonces el escenario que tenemos es que existe un objeto a cuyos atributos podemos acceder, mientras que todo el objeto es inaccesible porque no tiene un nombre. La solución es que uno de los atributos sea él mismo:

`<objetoGlobal>['window']=<objetoGlobal>` y/o `<objetoGlobal>['self']=<objetoGlobal>`

En los casos en los que trabajas con webWorkers no hay un atributo `window` en el objeto global, pero puedes usar `self`. Por supuesto, también se cumple que

```
self===self.self
```

Por tanto, cuando escribes `document`, el intérprete lo entiende como `<objetoGlobal>['document']` y cuando escribes `window.document` es como escribir `<objetoGlobal>['window'].document`.

Ambos atributos, `window` y `self` son de sólo lectura, no se puede modificar por motivos obvios.

El único escenario en que no puedes acceder a la ventana es que no estés en el contexto global y que se hayan creado las variables locales `self` y `window`, pero aún podrías acceder al resto de atributos globales.

Comment: Pero si window y document son una propiedad de Window, entonces document, no es una propiedad del objeto global, sino que de la propiedad window, que es a su vez propiedad de window, ya que puedo hacer: window.document.body.innerHTML = "";

Comment: Intento reescribir mi respuesta para aclarte tu duda.

Comment: Entonces la propiedad window, a su vez tiene todos los métodos y propiedades del objeto global?

Comment: Exacto, `window===window.window`

Answer (score 2):

Esto es así para facilitar el acceso a esta variable global y evitar que se confunda o pierda por culpa de plugins o extensiones que puedan crear una variable u objeto llamado window. Para una explicación más extendida te recomiendo que leas su documentación:

[API Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

Answer (score 2):

El objeto window tiene anidado el objeto window y así hasta el infinito. Algunas librerías comprueban que la variable window esté seteada para saber que están corriendo en un browser y no en node o en un webworker.

Para esto no basta verificar la existencia de la variable `window` que puede haber sido sobreescrita. Por eso revisan la anidación como un paso extra de verificación.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo que dice la documentacion sobre la propiedad [`Window.window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window):

> El punto de hacer que la propiedad  window se refiera al objeto en sí
>   mismo, probablemente haría que sea fácil referirse al objeto global.
>   De lo contrario, tendrías que hacer una var window = this; asignación
>   manual en la parte superior de tu script.
>
> Otra razón es que sin esta propiedad no podría escribir, por ejemplo,
>   " window.open('http://google.com/')". Debería usar "open"
>   ("http://google.com/") en su lugar.

Esto lo que quiere decir es que cuando accedemos al objeto `window`, en realidad estamos accediendo a la propiedad `window` de un objeto de tipo `Window` que esta definido globalmente.

En otras palabras esto:

```
window.open(url);
```

O esto `open(url)`(que al final se traduce a `window.open(url)`). Seria lo mismo que hacer esto:

```
var newWindow = new Window();
newWindow.open(url)
```

Pero como ya tenemos un objeto de tipo Window con la propiedad `window` definida , podemos hacer `window.open()`.