# Por qué la propiedad del objeto es aún accesible?

Tags: javascript

Por qué al obtener el elemento con id `"get"` no lanza ningún error, pero si obtengo otro, sí lanza error ? soy consciente de que **no estoy** llamandolo desde el objeto, pero entonces.. **no debería** también `get` lanzar error, además entiendo que get es una palabra reservada, pero por qué sucede esto, entonces le estoy cambiando el real valor de `get`, si es así me gustaría una aclaración documentada?

```js
(function () {
var us = {get: document.getElementById("get"),
          h6: document.getElementById("h6text")};
get.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("No error") });
h6.addEventListener("click", function(){ // error ?

});
})();
```

```html
<input value="Obtener" type="button" id="get">
<h6 id="h6text">Bienvenidos</h6>
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, el codigo hace lo que debería. Esa forma de ejecutar es para crear un entorno que no interfiera con funciones o variables globales externas. Ademas, h6 no existe. Lo que tienes es h6text que al tener id, deberia ser accesible como variable porque lo dice el estandard.

Comment: no se si me explico, tu agregas un tag en html, le pones id, y automáticamente lo puedes acceder como variable sin tener que usar getElementById() y eso es porque los tipos que crearon el estandard para Javascript lo pusieron en la especificación

Comment: Oh verdad, alguna vez lo escuche, gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los navegadores, por temas de compatibilidad con HTML antiguo (creado cuando el navegador mayoritario era Internet Explorer), a menudo han incorporado funcionalidades no estándar o incluso a menudo no recomendadas. Una de estas funcionalidades no recomendadas es poder acceder a cualquier elemento de la página usando su ID como si fuese un atributo de la clase `Window`. [Del repositorio de la W3C en GitHub](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object), si leemos la especificación de HTML5, podemos encontrar esto:

> **6.3.3. Named access on the Window object**
>
> **This definition is non-normative**. Implementation requirements are given below this definition.
>
> **window[name]**
>
> Returns the indicated element or collection of elements.
>   ***As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code***. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new
>   features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this,
>   use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector().

Que viene a significar, en pocas palabras, lo siguiente: funciona, pero no es buena idea usarlo. Es mejor acceder al DOM mediante los métodos `document.getElementById()` o `document.querySelector()`

Ejemplo del funcionamiento (lo pongo como muestra, pero recomiendo no usarlo):

```js
console.log(window.get.tagName);
console.log(window.h6text.innerHTML);
window.h6text.addEventListener('click',()=>alert('Has hecho click'));
```

```html
<input value="Obtener" type="button" id="get">
<h6 id="h6text">Click Me</h6>
```

Comment: Perdona pero esto no es del todo cierto... lo que tú refieres habla de los listeners del `window`... mientras que en el caso expuesto en la pregunta hablamos de elementos que se encuentran en el DOM, no en window... No es lo mismo. La [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) no afirma nada de lo que concluyes, y de hecho, muestra ejemplos casi similares, almacenando el elemento en una variable y luego añadiéndole el listener. Al menos eso es lo que yo entiendo.

Comment: Lo que quiero exponer es que, aunque no sea algo aconsejable, `window.<unID>` es lo mismo que `document.getElementById('<unID>');`

Comment: Esta afirmación: *poder acceder a cualquier elemento de la página usando su ID como si fuese un atributo de la clase Window* no la veo en el enlace. Luego, en tu código de ejemplo `window.h6text.addEventListener('click',()=>alert('Has hecho click'));` confundes `window` y `document`. **La práctica no recomendada es precisamente lo que haces en tu ejemplo**, usar el `window` (que es un elemento superior), para alcanzar un elemento que están en el `document` (inferior).  Tu código es contradictorio con los ejemplos de MDN al respecto y tu respuesta es confusa y quizá, no cierta del todo.

Comment: Mira el enlace que he puesto yo, de la W3C. La documentación de MDN no es fuente primaria, ellos sólo reflejan el estándar y no siempre está actualizada. Me parece normal que no pongan información sobre esta opción porque se recomienda no usarla, pero no significa nada en cuanto a que la fundación Mozilla no define lo que es o no es válido. Y sí, lo que hago en mi ejemplo es lo **no recomendado**

Comment: Precisamente, en el enlace que has puesto no leo lo que afirmas en la respuesta: ***poder acceder a cualquier elemento de la página usando su ID como si fuese un atributo de la clase Window***. En [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-EventListener) tampoco lo dice cuando habla de los listeners. Creo que cuando se hace esto: `unId.addEventListener(tipo, listener[, useCapture]);` no se invoca para nada a `window` sino que se busca ese elemento en el DOM (`document`).

Comment: Como ya expliqué [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116065/por-qu%C3%A9-sucede-esto/116073#116073), [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106042/var-let-const-o-nada-en-javascript/106067#106067) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100060/encontrar-variables-en-un-documento/100280#100280), no hace falta poner explícitamente `window.propiedad`, puesto que el intérprete ya asume que cualquier variable no declarada es un atributo de `window`. Por tanto `window.<id>` es lo mismo que `<id>`.

Comment: Eso es contradictorio con tu propio enlace: *the value of the id content attribute of any HTML element in the **active document** with a non-empty id content attribute.* Habla del documento activo, no de la ventana activa. Y en el enlace a Active Document dice esto: *Each Document in a browsing context is associated with a Window object.* No leo en ninguna parte de la doc lo que tú afirmas.

Answer (score 1):

### La documentación

Si revisas [la documentación de `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) verás que dice lo siguiente:

> `addEventListener()` Registra un evento a un objeto en específico. El
>   [Objeto específico](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget) puede ser un simple elemento en un archivo, el
>   mismo  documento , una ventana o un  XMLHttpRequest.

Verás también que la **sintaxis** es así:

```
target.addEventListener(tipo, listener[, useCapture]);
```

Aquí, `target` puede ser sustituido sin ningún problema por cualquier `id` de un elemento válido en el DOM.

---

### Lo que ocurre en tu código

De lo leído en la doc, podemos concluir que al agregar un listener de esta forma: `elId.addEventListener`, JS buscará en el DOM el elemento cuyo id sea igual a `elId`. Si lo encuentra bien, y si no lo encuentra dará error.

Por eso en tu código:

- Esto funciona: `get.addEventListener` porque en el DOM hay un elemento con un id igual a `get`
- Esto no funciona: `h6.addEventListener` porque no hay en el DOM ningún elemento con un id igual a `h6`.
- He agregado al DOM un elemento con `id="h6"`. Verás que tu anterior código erróneo, ya no lo es, porque se agrega un listener a ese elemento.

He hecho cosas a propósito en el código para que te des cuenta de lo que ocurre en realidad.

```js
(function(e) {
  var us = {
    get: document.getElementById("gets"),
    h6: document.getElementById("h6text")
  };
  gets.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("No error... Valor del elemento: " + us.get.value)
  });
  h6text.addEventListener("click", function() { // error ?
    console.log("No error... Id del elemento: " + us.h6.id)
  });
 h6.addEventListener("click", function() { // error ?
    console.log("ESTE ES EL LISTENER H6, SU ID ES: " + this.id)
  });
})();
```

```html
<input value="Obtener" type="button" id="gets">
<h6 id="h6text"><a href="#">Bienvenidos</a></h6>
<h6 id="h6"><a href="#">Esto sí que es H6</a></h6>
```

---

### ¿Palabras reservadas?

En cuanto a la duda sobre palabras reservadas, tuve la misma duda, plantee la pregunta hace un tiempo: [¿Palabras reservadas en HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/91037/29967) y la respuesta aceptada es muy clara.